# Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

I have this error:

> Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry\/(?P[0-9]+)$']

On line number 7:

*From _calender_entry.html*

```
<div class="calender_entry col-lg-4">
    <h2> {{ entry.name }} </h2>
    <h4> {{ entry.date }} </h4>
    <p>
        {{ entry.description }}
    </p>
    <button onclick="window.location='{% url 'details' pk=entry.id %}'" class="btn btn-primary"> View Details </button>
</div>
```

This is from my ***urls.py*** file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('entry/<int:pk>', views.details, name='details'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And here is method from ***views.py*** :

```
def index(request):
entries = Entry.objects.all()
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'entries' : entries})

def details(request, pk):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'myapp/details.html', {'entry' : entry})
```

Here is ***models.py***

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.date}'
```

The _calender_entry.html is included in index.html file as follows:

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for entry in entries %}
                {% include 'myapp/_calender_entry.html' %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could anyone be able to tell me how could I fix this problem?

Comment: `entry.id` is empty, and that doesn’t match the requirement `<int:pk>` (what would it link to?).

Comment: YOu do not show any `entry.id` in _calender_entry.html

Comment: show me the model

Comment: Do you have any data in entry model? If the model is going to be empty, then details.html will render empty and entry.id is empty and thus url doesn't make match and throws error of reverse not found.

Comment: Hi @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas here I added the model for adding data.

Comment: Hi @chiseledCoder. Yes i have data in entry model. And it worked fine when I just rendered from model I have created. The error came only when I added onclick function to button

Comment: Show me tha function of the template From _calender_entry.html

Comment: The function of template is added in views.py @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas. And also added index file where _calender_entry.html is included

Comment: I know. what I want to see is if in that function you are passing the entry variable, because everything else seems to be fine

Comment: @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas you can also refer to full code on github here: https://github.com/NikhilOO7/calenderApp

Comment: I'll review it and I'll tell you in a little while

Comment: Thanks @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas.

Answer (score 0):

now django forces you that each app has its own urls.py.

Create the urls.py file in the myapp/ directory

```
# myapp/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('entry/<int:pk>/', views.details, name='details'),
]
```

the urls.py of the project has to be as follows

```
# calenderproject/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('myapp.urls', 'myapp'), namespace='myapp')),
]
```

use in the template as follows

```
# myapp/_calender_entry.html
<a href="{% url 'myapp:details' pk=entry.id %}" class="btn btn-primary"> View Details </a>
```

that's how it works, I've checked

I found the error, delete this code from the template _calender_entry.html

```
<!-- {% include 'myapp/_calender_entry.html' %} -->
```

although this commented with html django equal it executes it to comment in the template uses `{# {% include 'myapp / _calender_entry.html'%} #}` in this way django does not execute it

Comment: Tried same thing but still getting same error. And can you please translate above in English

Comment: upload your changes to git to check

Comment: I have uploaded the changes to github. Please check

Comment: I have modified my answer, I hope I have helped you. A greeting.

Comment: Thank you so much Jimy Hendrix Falcón Cárdenas. It really helped !

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Do not forget to mark your question as answered. Greetings.